# Analytic function with alternating taylor series

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, exponential-function

Is there a characterization of the sequences of non-negative real numbers $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^{\infty}$ such that
$$
f(x)=\sum_{n\geq 0}a_n (-x)^n
$$
converges absolutely for all $x\geq 0$?

It's not hard to see that this condition fails to hold whenever $a_n$ decreases at most exponentially in $n$. When $a_n$ decreases superexponentially in $n$, things get trickier; the only examples I can think of are based on $e^{-x}$, and they satisfy the condition.

**More quantitatively:** Is it true that the above condition holds if and only if $\limsup_n \frac{1}{n}\log a_n=-\infty$?

Comment: The minus before $x$ is irrelevant since we want the series to converge absolutely. Wouldn't it now suffice to apply Cauchy-Hadamard theorem?